# Strange type class declaration

Tags: c++, class, opencv

I'm trying to understand functionality of **OpenCv** library. I saw following strange type class declaration code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp#L929).

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W Subdiv2D
{
    // code here
};
```

I don't understand, What does `Subdiv2D` do with class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Subdiv2D` is the name of the [class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class). The `CV_EXPORTS_W` part is probably some macro or an alias specific to Windows implementation.